# Eclipse Java debug mode: how to get actual type of value?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

The variable view of Eclipse Java Debug mode allows to inspect the values of variables.  If the type of a variable has several sub-types, how to find out the actual type of the value?

Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800

Comment: What do you mean by `actual type of the value` ?

Comment: you have to distinguish between the static type and the dynamic type of a variable, but doesn't eclipse show the dynamic type of a variable in the variables view by default?

Comment: I meant the dynamic type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use expressions view. If for example your variable name is `x` add `x.getClass()` to expressions view and see the type.

Answer (score 1):

use **`ctrl+shift+I`** for  inspect expressions/variables in debug mode of eclipse

let say i have below code

**Example:**

```
List<String> strLst = commonService.getUserdetail();
```

and i want to know value of strLst than

select `commonService.getUserdetail()` and than press ctrl+shift+I
it will give you value that comes from `commonService.getUserdetail()` method

go  [HERE](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) to know more about debuging in eclipse

Comment: He said the type of value. Not the value.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easier with [Eclipse 4.17 (2020-09 release)](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/jdt.php#variables-actual-type):

> ### Actual type in Variables view
>
> The option **`Show Type Names`** in the **Variables and Expressions views** now displays the value's actual type instead of its declared type.
> This simplifies debugging especially when variable details (`toString()`) is shown **As the label for all variables**.
>
> To enable **`Show Type Names`** in the **Variables view**, column mode must be disabled (`View Menu > Layout > Show Columns`).
>
> Example:
>
> ```java
> Object s = "some string";
> Collection<?> c = Arrays.asList(s, 1);
> // breakpoint
> ```
>
> [image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/images/variables-actual-type.png]